# Problems to convert a QString to QDateTime

Tags: regex, qt, qdatetime, qdate

i have a problem to convert a `QString` to a `QDataTime`-Object.

The String looks like: `"2008:09:23 14:18:03` and have a length of 20.
The Problem is, if i remove the first character the output looks like: `"008:09:23 14:18:03`.

That's wrong with it?
Can i delete all characters without the numbers?

The code:

```
        QDateTime date;
        QString d=QString::fromStdString(result.val_string);
        date.fromString(d,"yyyy:MM:dd hh:mm:ss");
        qDebug()<<d;
        qDebug()<<d.length()<<date.toString();
```

And the output:

```
 "008:09:23 14:18:03
 19 ""
```

Greetings

Comment: Why would you remove the first character?

Comment: if i use date.fromString(d,"\"yyyy:MM:dd hh:mm:ss"); the result is the same.

Comment: Oh, I see, you have a doublequote at the beginning of the string. Can you show us how you removed the first character from `result.val_string`?

Comment: for this  used `.remove(0,1)`

Comment: i tested also d.replace("\"","");...but the " is still at the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double quotes are printed by the `qDebug`, they are not included in the `QString` itself. However, it seems that you have some non-printable character at the end of the original string which deletes the closing `"` sign. Try to copy only first 19 characters into the `QString`:

```
    QString d = QString::fromStdString(result.val_string.substr(0, 19));
    date.fromString(d,"yyyy:MM:dd hh:mm:ss");
    qDebug()<<d;
    qDebug()<<d.length()<<date.toString();
```

**EDIT** `QDateTime.fromString` is the static method returning the `QDateTime` object - it will not modify the object itself!

```
QDateTime date;
std::string val_string = "2008:09:23 14:18:03";
QString d = QString::fromStdString(val_string.substr(0, 19));
date = QDateTime::fromString(d,"yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss");
qDebug()<<d;
qDebug()<<d.length()<<date.toString();
```

Comment: I tested this. But the result is the same. The Output looks like `"2008:09:23 14:18:03" ` but it doesn't recognize the date

Answer (score 0):

Use `qPrintable(string);` and it will get rid of the double quotes.

It isn't a problem with how the date makes the string.  Its how `qDebug` handles strings.  A `char *` is different from a `QString` according to `QDebug`.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtglobal.html#qPrintable

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#toLocal8Bit

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qbytearray.html#constData

Hope that helps.